# Skip menu div and show contents

Tags: css

On the WordPress theme I am working on https://themes.getmotopress.com/2019/ the menu turns into a circle and excess menu items are put into this when the screen resolution decreases.

[image]

I would like to stop `<div class="main-menu-more">` from showing and all elements become listed in the main container. I have used the code

```
.main-navigation .main-menu-more {
    display:none;
}
```

Which hides the more menu however the elements inside do not show?

Comment: can you show a demo link?

Comment: If you reduce the size of your browser small enough you will see the circle menu appear on https://themes.getmotopress.com/2019/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this style I hope this will work for you but you should have to upgrade style according to your requirement**

```
 @media (max-width:500px){
.submenu-expand{
    display: none;
}
.main-navigation .sub-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
}
.main-navigation .sub-menu > li > a, .main-navigation .sub-menu > li > .menu-item-link-return {
    color: #0073aa;
}
.sub-menu:hover{
position: relative;
}
}
```

Comment: I added the code but nothing appeared to happen. Please note my website menu turns into a mobile version at 1024px. I applied the code above to https://seoace.com.au/

Comment: Change media query according to your screen resolution for eg. @media (max-width:1024px) { //add css here }

Comment: I tried that but the result is the same. Not even the circle menu is disappering.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. There is another menu after "Style Guide". Please look at screenshot to see which menu I am referring to,

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the source codes of the WordPress you are currently working and determined that by deleting the word "toggle" from class="submenu-expand main-menu-more-toggle  is-empty" which will become class="submenu-expand main-menu-more is-empty" will no longer hide the menus in the circle, but will simply become part of the responsive webpage.

The code came from the button section of your WordPress. Simply search for the class attribute with a value of "submenu-expand main-menu-more-toggle" using the search function on your text editor and delete the word "toggle" from it. It worked for me.

Let me know how it went.

Comment: I think you are on the right track but I would like to achieve this using CSS?